# Exoplayer throw NotProvisionedException when MediaDrm.openSession()

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am trying to make drm video play in exoplayer and i have custom licence request

```
val mediaDrm = MediaDrm(C.WIDEVINE_UUID)  

val sessionId = mediaDrm.openSession()
```

when I run this line of code I am getting that is NotProvisionedException

I am trying to generate key by this line

```
mediaDrm.getKeyRequest(sessionId,listOf(schemeData),mimType)
```

in order to get sessionId i m writing below code

```
val mediaDrm = MediaDrm(C.WIDEVINE_UUID)
val sessionId = mediaDrm.openSession()
```

Answer (score 0):

That error is telling you that the DRM system you are asking to create a MediaDRM object for is not provisioned on your device.

The most common cause of this is either an incorrect UUID being passed to MediaDRM or the device not actually supporting the DRM system, WideVine in your case.

You can check if your device has widvine provisioned and Laos the level of wide vine supported using the DrmManagerClient.acquireDrmInfo() method:

- https://support.google.com/widevine/answer/6072714?hl=en

Note that if you are testing on an emulator DRM will usual not work correctly.